# Chrome dev tools network tab and base64 inlined fonts lag

Tags: asynchronous, fonts, base64, font-face, woff

For a site I'm building, I'm trying to get the absolute best performance possible via some inline font / async JS loading in the head.  In order to get around the extra http requests and delayed load required by Typekit font loading, I've opted to base 64 encode my woff / woff2 fonts (FontAwesome, Lato, Lato Bold) in my LESS / CSS.  When running locally, I've got my DOMContentLoaded (blue bar) down to 30 ms but the font inlining it appears is causing my actual load time (red bar) to be 280 ms.

[image: Network]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="tix.app" ng-strict-di ng-cloak class="wf-loading">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- blocks to hide FOUT -->
  <style>.wf-loading [class^="icon-"], .wf-loading [class*=" icon-"], .wf-loading h1, .wf-loading h2, .wf-loading h3, .wf-loading h4, .wf-loading div, .wf-loading p, .wf-loading span, .wf-loading a, .wf-loading ul, .wf-loading li .wf-loading i {  visibility: hidden !important;  }</style>
  <!-- starts download of dependent libraries (angular / d3 / jquery..) -->
  <script src="/app/depends.js.gz" async defer></script>
  <!-- starts download of angular app, has a check to ensure depends is downloaded first -->
  <script src="/app/tix.js.gz" async defer></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Angular SPA</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- blocks to download inline base64 fonts and bootstrap based styles -->
  <link href="/assets/css/tix.min.css.gz" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- script to tell the page that CSS has finished loading so show text (wf-active) -->
  <script src="/app/tix.fast.js.gz" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <angular-stuff></angular-stuff>
</body>
</html>
```

**depends.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = require('angular');
require('./d3.min');
require('./jquery-1.9.1.min');
require('./jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min');
require('./socket.io-1.3.4.js');
require('./ui-bootstrap-tpls.js');
require('angular-route');
require('angular-bootstrap');
require('angular-animate');
require('angular-loading-bar');
require('./ngStorage');

window.dependsLoaded = window.dependsLoaded || function () {};
window.dependsLoaded();
```

**tix.js**

```
window.isDependsLoaded = false;
function dependsLoaded() {
    // App code
}
window.dependsLoaded = dependsLoaded;

// If angular already exists and the dependencies haven't been loaded, depends.js must have finished loading first -> manually initialize
if(window.angular && !window.isDependsLoaded) {
    window.dependsLoaded();
}
```

**tix.fast.js**

```
(function (d) {
  d.documentElement.className = "wf-active";
}(document));
```

The tix.less (tix.css) imports all fonts via @font-face like so -

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,......) format('woff2'),
       url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,......) format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

As you can see I hide all text elements with my inline CSS and manual "wf-inactive" class on the html element.  I then async load my main scripts prior to loading my CSS fonts (so that the downloads will start prior to css blocking).  depends.js has all the external libraries I'm dependent on (AngularJS, jquery, signalr, etc.).  tix.js contains all my app logic (the actual angular app, and is much smaller than depends.js, but will get updated more often so I split them to benefit from depends.js caching).  After the async scripts, I then have my css file load (all styles bundled in one CSS file, including my inlined base 64 fonts) which blocks, after that finishes loading I then load tix.fast.js which simply updates the html class to "wf-active", setting the page text to visible (emulating Typekit).

I'm basically seeing additional network latency per each font that is inlined within the network tab.  This confuses me for a few reasons:

1. Why are these inlined fonts considered network requests in the first place?  They use the url(data....) tag, but the whole point in inlining them is to avoid a network request so what's going on here?  To me, the network request was downloading the file they were embedded in but maybe there are more hops required when loading the font?
2. I am trying to minimize the number of http calls since chrome only allows 6 simultaneous.  Is that the reason that my fonts are getting hung up?  Is it because the DOM isn't trying to access them until closer to the red load point and @font-face is just lazy loading them at that time?  What are my best options to instrument this?

Comment: Did you ever find a way around the delay? I'm dealing with a similar issue

Comment: @JoeSloth - Nope, my focus shifted a bit so I haven't tested it lately.  I'm working on performance testing again finally though so I will post an update when I get down to this level nitty gritty again.